# Incorrect results of modulo operation between large numbers in R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x

To solve a puzzle from [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/summing-the-n-series/problem?isFullScreen=true), I'm trying to apply modulo operations between large numbers in R (v4.2.2). However, I get incorrect results when at least one of the operands is very large. For example, `52504222585724001 %% 10` yields `0` in R. which is incorrect. However, when I try `52504222585724001 % 10` in python (v3.9.12) I get the correct result `1`. So I decided to test some other numbers. I downloaded a set of test cases for which my code was failing and I did `n*n mod (10^9 + 7)` for each `n` value.

### R code:

```
summingSeries <- function(n) {
  return(n^2 %% (10^9 + 7))
}

n <- c(229137999, 344936985, 681519110, 494844394, 767088309, 307062702, 306074554, 555026606, 4762607, 231677104)
expected <- c( 218194447, 788019571, 43914042, 559130432, 685508198, 299528290, 950527499, 211497519, 425277675, 142106856 )

result <- rep(0L, length(n))

start <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:length(n)){
  result[i] <- summingSeries(n[i])
}
print(Sys.time() - start)
df <- data.frame(expected, result, diff = abs(expected - result))
print(df)
```

I am pasting below the results and the absolute differences with the expected values

```
expected    result   diff
-------------------------
218194447 218194446    1
788019571 788019570    1
43914042  43914070    28
559130432 559130428    4
685508198 685508205    7
299528290 299528286    4
950527499 950527495    4
211497519 211497515    4
425277675 425277675    0
142106856 142106856    0
```

### Python3 code:

```
import numpy as np

def summingSeries(n):
    return(n ** 2 % (10 ** 9 + 7))

n = [229137999,
    344936985,
    681519110,
    494844394,
    767088309,
    307062702,
    306074554,
    555026606,
    4762607,
    231677104]

expected = [218194447,
    788019571,
    43914042,
    559130432,
    685508198,
    299528290,
    950527499,
    211497519,
    425277675,
    142106856]

result = [0] * len(n)
for i in range(0, len(n)):
  result[i] = summingSeries(n[i])

print(np.array(result) -  np.array(expected))
```

I get the correct results using the above python code. Can someone kindly explain why there are inconsistencies and why R is yielding the wrong results?

Comment: Well, Python has arbitrarily sized integer objects. In R, you are using "doubles" (64 bit binary floating point), so that would probably explain it. If you use `float` objects in Python, you get the same behavior.

Comment: Note, integer type is to small in R, AFAIKT it's a 32bit signed? Sheesh. Try looking up arbitrary-sized integer libraries in R and using that. Though take care that operations don't promote to regular, fixed-sized types like `double`

Comment: A simple experiment in which you try `x = 52504222585724001`  and read back the result in R would expose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `gmp` package (see Carl Witthoft's comment).

```
gmp::mod.bigz(gmp::as.bigz(n)^2, 1e9 + 7) - expected
#> Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 10:
#>  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Previous/inferior answer:

```
library(Rmpfr)

n <- c(229137999, 344936985, 681519110, 494844394, 767088309, 307062702, 306074554, 555026606, 4762607, 231677104)
expected <- c(218194447, 788019571, 43914042, 559130432, 685508198, 299528290, 950527499, 211497519, 425277675, 142106856)
data.frame(
  precision = 53:64, # 53 corresponds to double precision
  sumAbsErr = sapply(53:64, function(p) sum(abs(expected - as.numeric(mpfr(n, p)^2 %% (1e9 + 7)))))
)
#>    precision sumAbsErr
#> 1         53        53
#> 2         54        29
#> 3         55        21
#> 4         56        16
#> 5         57         1
#> 6         58         1
#> 7         59         1
#> 8         60         0
#> 9         61         0
#> 10        62         0
#> 11        63         0
#> 12        64         0
```

60 bits of precision is just enough for this example.

Comment: Rmpfr is **very risky** when you want integer ops.   Use  `gmp:as.bigz` to work with arbitrary size integers.  Apply the gmp-specific function `mod.bigz(e1, e2)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, `gmp::mod.bigz(gmp::as.bigz(n)^2, 1e9 + 7) - expected` is a much better answer. I'll delete this if you want to add it.

Comment: thanks; I have points to burn, so keep it as part of your answer.